# Eclipse CDT indexer cannot resolve ae_f32 type

Tags: c++, eclipse, signal-processing, eclipse-cdt

While trying to port floating-point C code to a fixed-point code, I came accross a problem in Eclipse CDT - indexer does not recognize `f32` type which I am using to replace standard C `float`. The code compiles and builds fine (using MinGW GCC compiler). It's a mixture of C and C++ code.

It is annoying to see hundreds of warnings in Eclipse: `Type f32 could not be resolved`. This is how the type is defined in the 3rd party DSP library code:

```
#define B_(X) b_##X
... 
#define f32 B_(f32) 
... 
/* type declarations */

#define DECLARE_TYPE(s) \
    namespace s##_space { \
    class s##_; \
    } \
    typedef s##_space::s##_ s;
... 
DECLARE_TYPE(f32);
...
namespace f32_space 
{
    //etc...
```

Why wouldn't `f32` type be recognized?

Comment: This works for me (or at least an approximate version of what you have put in here). Can you edit to make it [MCVE]? (To be specific, ae_f32 works, but ae_f32x2 does not, however the latter has no declaration in your question.)

Comment: Sorry, can't do compelte example... What do you mean by "works for me"? Eclipse doesn't report `Type ae_f32 could not be resolved`? ae_f32x2 is not important, only ae_f32 is.

Comment: Yes, If I cut down your example and stick it in a new C++ project it *just works* for `ae_f32`. This is what I used in my cutdown: http://pastebin.com/KfmpEsbX

Comment: Thanks Jonah. Well, that just makes it more puzzling.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the size of include file? The .h file has more than 30.000 lines.

Comment: @Danijel: It could be. Can you post (a link to) the entire .h file?

Comment: Sorry @HighCommander4, can't do that, it's 3rd party copyrighted file.

Comment: Is there maybe a plugin that can replace default Indexer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it.

The problem was mixture of C and C++ in `.c` files. I have sources with `.c` extension that have ifdefed C++ code `(#if defined(__cplusplus)` etc), and also compiler is set to C++. Indexer however parses those files as C. When I generated indexer log file (Project\C C++ Index\Create Parser Log File), I noticed the following: `Language: GNU C`.

Then I added language mappings:

`Settings\C C++ General\Language Mappings`

- `C Header file` map to `C++`
- `C Source file` map to `C++`

Once I changed this, it works.